# Sorting table rows rooted from custom attribute and text in td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Stuck, I need to sort a table based off a custom attribute in the table row for each level then based off the text in the td itself. So for all levels go through and sort a higher level

So I have:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr data-level="1" data-parent="0"><td>3</td></tr>
<tr data-level="1" data-parent="0"><td>1</td></tr>
<tr data-level="2" data-parent="1"><td>1b</td></tr>
<tr data-level="2" data-parent="1"><td>1c</td></tr>
<tr data-level="2" data-parent="1"><td>1a</td></tr>
<tr data-level="1" data-parent="0"><td>2</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

my expectation would look like this:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr data-level="1" data-parent="0"><td>1</td></tr>
<tr data-level="2" data-parent="1"><td>1a</td></tr>
<tr data-level="2" data-parent="1"><td>1b</td></tr>
<tr data-level="2" data-parent="1"><td>1c</td></tr>
<tr data-level="1" data-parent="0"><td>2</td></tr>
<tr data-level="1" data-parent="0"><td>3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried this:

```
function sortMultilevel(level){

    var $sort = this;
    var $table = $('table');
    var $rows = $('tbody > tr[data-level="'+level+'"]',$table);
    $rows.sort(function(a, b){
        var keyA = $('td',a).text();
        var keyB = $('td',b).text();
        if($($sort).hasClass('asc')){
            return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : 0;
        } else {
            return (keyA < keyB) ? 0 : 1;
        }
    });
    $.each($rows, function(index, row){
      $table.append(row);
    });
}

function doMultilevelSort(){

    if($("tr").length > 0){
        $("tr").not(".sorted").each(function(){
            $(this).addClass("sorted");
            var level = $(this).attr("data-level");
            sortMultilevel(level);
            console.log("sorting: " + level);
        });
    }   
}

doMultilevelSort(); // call the function
```

I may be way over thinking this.  If I am I am your student and I am all ears.  Appreciate the look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/zrQyu/)

```
$('#sort').click(function (e) {
    var $table = $('#sort_me');
    var $rows = $('tbody > tr', $table);
    $rows.sort(function (a, b) {
        var keyA = $('td', a).text();
        var keyB = $('td', b).text();
        return (keyA > keyB) ? 1 : 0;
    });
    $.each($rows, function (index, row) {
        $table.append(row);
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Also, kind of related - in Javascript is 10 greater than  the letter A? Or are numbers before letters or letters before numbers in sorting?

Comment: its still related to the text  content of table  data, i think is must be sort via table row attribute.